# How to protect your app from hackers

Tags: android

I am currently coding a bible application for android. This app is intended to be for the use of a certain church. The problem is that this church has been heavily attacked in too many ways. One of them is cybernetic-ally. I am just wondering how do I protect my app from being hacked in google play?. I also want to point out that I am coding this without the authorization from the church, but in the event I get authorized, what would be the protocol to defend the app? or what do I need to study?. Is it possible an app gets hacked in google play?.

What I mean by hacking is that is it possible that some engineer can access the code within google play and changed the app's content?

Comment: The key with which you digitally sign the app should be more than enough.

Comment: It looks like we have an invasion of downvoters in google play.

Comment: Defend it from what?  "Hacking" is too broad a term.  This question is unanswerable without details of what the app is and how it works, and the threat vector you're worried about.

Comment: Ok defend it from being changed by "hackers" people

Comment: People downvoting an app is not hacking. There is not really anything you can do in that regard. Also see @Gabe's comment.

Comment: I updated the thread.

Comment: Changed where?  On the Google Play servers?  That's built in with the cryptographic signatures, as long as you don't give away your password to Google Play or the signing key.  On the local device?  Nothing can prevent that.

Comment: I think there is no reason for downvoting. I am new to android development

Comment: What is the church doing to provoke the downvotes? That's the real cause of the problem. In any case, this question is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you keep your signing certificate in a safe place no one will be able to replace your application file in the Google Play by something else.

Google Play does filter out offensive feedback but if people will find your app unfriendly your app rating will be low and there will be negative (non-offensive) feedback.

There are several companies to hire who can provide good positive feedback  for an app if you pay for that, but this is cheating somewhat.